# ML-programming in Isabelle (beginner)

Tags: isabelle

I am learning how to write ML code in Isabelle (just started).

I am following the explanation and the examples in "The Isabelle Cookbook" (2013) and using Isabelle2017.

The function `term_of` and `prop_of` cannot be used anymore?
Examples on page 12 give rise to ML error:

```
ML error⌂:
Value or constructor (prop_of) has not been declared
```

What are the new functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these need to be namespaced now: `Thm.prop_of` and `Thm.term_of`.